# The width of characters are not the same in IDEA editor

Tags: intellij-idea

In IDEA gerkin editor, I found that the width of spaces and other characters are not the same.
I couldn't make the the pipe(|) aligned.
Is there a way to make the width the same?

IDEA:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

**Solution**:
Changing to other Fonts, like `Fira Code`.
[image]

Comment: What font are you using in the editor? Most likely the problem can be solved by switching to a different monospaced font.

Comment: I'm using `Monospaced`.

Comment: Try switching to Fira Code (which is bundled with recent IntelliJ IDEA versions)

Comment: After changing to `Consolas`, they become the same. Thank you

Comment: `Fira Code` also works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Monospaced` is not a real font, it's just an alias and the real font that will be used depends on the OS, JDK and other factors.

It looks like in your case the font chosen is not actually monospaced (fixed width).

Changing the font to any other real fixed width font in the IDE Editor settings will resolve the problem.